# How to convert Pandas DataFrame to byte array and retrieve it back using numpy rec arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

Please go through the code, I have mentioned problem within it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

print("hello")
data = np.array([['', 'Col1', 'Col2'], ['Row1', 1, 2], ['Row2', 3, 4]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:, 1:], columns=data[0, 1:])
print(df)

df_to_records = df.to_records(index=False)

records_to_bytes = df_to_records.tobytes()

'''
encryption, decryption code here using cryptography.fernet  . It takes bytes 
as input and gives bytes as output.   
'''
# How can I retrieve DataFrame from records_to_bytes. I can easily retrieve 
# from df_to_records

df_retrieved = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df_to_records)

# What I need is

# df_retrieved = pd.DataFrame.from_records("Inverse operation of 
# df_to_records.tobytes()")

print(df_retrieved)
```

Any alternate method is also appreciated as long as it serves the purpose:
Create pandas frame --> Convert it to bytes (cryptography.Fernet takes bytearray as input). --> encrypt. Decrypt and get DataFrame back.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.frombuffer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) with the `dtype` argument explicitly set to the `dtype` of your record array. However note that `nummpy.frombuffer` cannot operate on python `Object` type. If your dataframe contains strings, make sure to type cast them as `numpy fixed width string types`